# Trying to figure out how to codesign a blackberry app

Tags: blackberry, code-signing

I just finished my first black berry app and I'm assuming I must codesign it before sub.
On my eclipse there is a option to install new signature keys. How do I get a signature key?  I could not find no options in eclipse to then sign the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to run your application in the simulator without signing it, but in order to run it on a real device you will indeed have to get signing keys and sign your application. In order to get code signing keys, you will have to fill out a registration form [here](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/codekeys.jsp). BlackBerry recently simplified this process, but there are still several steps to it and once you fill out that application you'll still need to wait for RIM to give you your keys and further instructions. Once you have your keys, you can use the eclipse option to install them and use them when building your application, so that you can deploy it to a real device (this option is available in the preferences for the blackberry plugin).